# Transformation from Hypergeometric to Whittaker.

Tags: operator-theory, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, eigenfunctions

I'm working on an eigenvalue problem involving 2 operators, which we will call $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$. They are related for very small values on a coordinate $x \approx 0$, in which $\hat{A}$ transforms into $\hat{B}$, because the former has hyperbolic sine terms that reduce into $\sinh(x) \approx x$ in this limit, resulting in $\hat{B}$. As such we expect for the eigenfunctions of $\hat{A}$ to also transform accordingly into the eigenfunctions of $\hat{B}$, for very small values of $x$.

The eigenfunctions for $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, respectively are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ given by:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = C_1 e^{x(\alpha + \beta)} (1-e^{2x})^{\frac{1}{2} + i \nu} \text{ }_2F_1\left(\alpha + \frac{1}{2} + i \nu,\beta + \frac{1}{2} + i \nu; 1 + \alpha + \beta;e^{2x}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 g(x) = C_2 W_{\beta, i\nu} (2|\alpha| x)
\end{equation}

However, I'm having trouble demonstrating that for $x \approx 0$,
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = g(x)
\end{equation}
In particular, I've been trying to use the integral representations of the Hypergeometric function and applying the limit under consideration but so far I haven't been able to transform it into a Whittaker representation.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = g(x)$ does not make much sense since the left-hand side does not depend on $x$. You have to do a re-sclaing in the hypergeometric equation and take a limit to pass to the confluent hypergeometric equation.

Comment: I understand what you mean, my mistake. I phrased it wrong and fixed the post now. My intention was to say that for very small values of $x \approx 0$, we expect to obtain the relation $f(x) = g(x)$. More specifically, this comes from the fact that for these values, the operator $\hat{A}$ has hyperbolic sine terms which reduce to $\sinh(x) \approx x$, giving the form of the operator $\hat{B}$.

Comment: Use $e^{at}=1+at$